# How to update a table form itself?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table A. I want to increment a field by 1.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
a1 integer,
a2 integer
)

INSERT INTO A (a1, a2)
   VALUES (1, 1); 


update A ANEW set 
(a1,a2)=(select a1,a2+1 from A AOLD where ANEW.a1=AOWL.a1)
```

> ORA-00904: "AOWL"."A1": invalid identifier

```
FORALL i IN INDICES of (select a1, a2 from A ) t
    update INTO A 
          VALUES (t(i).a1,t(i).a2+1)
          where A.a1=t(i).a1;
```

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

```
MERGE into A AOLD
using (select a1,a2+1 from A) ANEW on (ANEW.a1=aOLD.a1)
        WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE SET
                ANEW.a1=AOLD.a1,
                ANEw.a2=AOLD.a2+1;
```

> ORA-00904: "ANEW"."A1": invalid identifier.

None of this solution is working

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=69e093ca863da1a8223df31b41ce329f)

Comment: I don't understand. How is what you are trying to do different from a mere `update a set a2 = a2 + 1`?

Comment: I added a "batch" to your [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=93ee3ffbd93490151c1e13d70dc72cc6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up your syntax on the merge statement. Try this (note that I've relabelled the aliases as "tgt" and "src" to help you understand where the columns are coming from):

```
MERGE into A tgt
using (select a1,
              a2+1 a2_new from A) src
  on (tgt.a1=src.a1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET tgt.a2=src.a2_new;
```

Note that I gave the a2 column in your source query an alias; you can now use that in the update part. Also, since you can't update a column that's in the join condition, I've removed that from the update part.

However, if all you're wanting to do is add 1 to the value of a column, why not just:

```
update a
set    a2 = a2 + 1;
```

?

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=03500d0c4e24a260da446cacbb52b877)

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt at the update will work successfully, you were just using the wrong alias. You were using AOWL instead of AOLD.

```sql
UPDATE A ANEW
   SET (a1, a2) =
           (SELECT a1, a2 + 1
              FROM A AOLD
             WHERE ANEW.a1 = AOLD.a1);
```

But the update can be simplified even more without needing to subquery

```sql
UPDATE a
   SET a2 = a2 + 1;
```